# Python IndexError: list index out of range while finding SNPs in vcf

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, range, vcf-vcard

Hi all I am supposed to use a Python script to identify possible SNPs at specified positions  from a csv file in vcf files.
I just started using python and sadly I always get following Error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "getSNPs.py", line 20, in <module>    oo = line[2] + "_" +
 line[3]
 IndexError: list index out of range from the following script
 !/bin/python usage: python getSNPs.py your.vcf PhenoSNPs.csv
```

**Code:**

```
import sys
import gzip

SNPs = {}

for i in gzip.open(sys.argv[1], "r"):
    if '#' not in i:
        line = i.split("\t")
        oo = line[0] + "_" + line[1]
        SNPs[oo] = i

pp = sys.argv[1] + ".captureSNPs"

out = open(pp, "w")

for i in open(sys.argv[2], "r"):
    line = i.split(",")
    oo = line[2] + "_" + line[3]
    try:
        out.write(SNPs[oo])
    except KeyError:
        ow = line[2] + "\t" + line[3] + "\t" + "not covered" + "\n"
        out.write(ow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for instance `i = 'aa'` and you do `line = i.split(",")` it implies that `line = ['aa']`, then you will get an `IndexError` when you do `line[2] + "_" + line[3]` because `line` doesn't have 2nd and 3rd elements.

Use `try/except` or re-think the logic of your code.